# VBA: Page break only after certain rows

Tags: vba, excel, page-break

I'm automatically populating an excel with a macro in Excel. The resulting sheet might look like the following:

```
|1. TOYS-----------|

|LEGO--------------|

|Product 1|199,99--|

|Product Text------|

|Product 2|299,99--|

|Product Text------|

|MARVEL------------|

|Product 3|79,99---|

|Product Text------|

|2. FOOD-----------|

|Vegetables--------|

|Product 4|9,99----|

|Product Text------|

|Product 5|2,99----|

|Product Text------|
```

When I print this list, the page breaks are created randomly and might cut through an article (i.e. name and price on page 1, text on page 2).

How can I tell the macro to only allow page breaks after the row containing "product text". Unfortunately, I can't tell him to do it every x rows because due to the grouping rows, the steps are not always the same.

Thanks

Comment: keep `|Product Text------|` as the first row only (erase all other occurrences) and then set "Page Layout -> Sheet -> Row to repeat at top" selecting first row

Answer (score 0):

After pasting the "Product text" block, check which row you are, and assign it to variable `TarRow`. Then use this:

`Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(TarRow).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual`

I'm assuming you are on Sheet 1 and have a loop so if you insert this in your loop, it'll work out for all products?

For the future, please keep in mind that it's always better to give an example so that we can see the code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Wouldn't that add a line break after every product though? I want the page breaks to be dynamic (i.e. whenever they are needed to fill the page), but with the restriction to only appear after the details rows

Comment: much harder... because in excel, "when they are needed" is itself dynamic. Maybe you could specify some buffer and say "after you've seen the details row, you're allowed to insert a page-break for 10 rows"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub add_HPBreak()

Dim HPBreak As HPageBreak
Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long


'set your last row as required
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Rows.Count + 1
ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview

For i = 1 To lastrow

        For Each HPBreak In ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks
        'assuming product text string is in column 1
        If InStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value, "product text") > 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Select
            ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=ActiveCell

        End If

    Next

Next

ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView


End Sub
```